# Check multiple items in ASP.NET CheckboxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I try to check multiple values in ASP.NET CheckboxList but I couldn't.

I Wrote :

```
chkApplications.SelectedValue = 2;
chkApplications.SelectedValue = 6;
```

But it just selects item with value '6'
What's wrong ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best technique that will work for you is the following:

```
chkApplications.Items.FindByValue("2").Selected = true;
chkApplications.Items.FindByValue("6").Selected = true;
```

OR you can simply do it like...

```
  foreach (ListItem item in chkApplications.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == "2" || item.Value == "6")
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That will throw exception if value is not found. Also needs to iterate the complete collection once for every call to `FindByValue`.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (var item in cb.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where (li => li.Value == "2" || li.Value == "6"))
   item.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can put the value in a list (`MyList`), and use `FindByValue` to check them.

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    checkBoxList.Items.FindByValue(item.id).Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to select the item through `chkApplications.SelectedValue` try 
`chkApplications.Items.Item(2).Selected = True`
`chkApplications.Items.Item(6).Selected = True`