# Save multiple values checkboxList

Tags: c#, umbraco

I got this

```
foreach (string itemm in member.getProperty("categories").Value.ToString().Split(','))
{
     Cbl_items.SelectedValue = itemm;
}
```

And this only makes the last "itemm" selected , how can i do this for 3 or 4 ?

Comment: what is cbl_items? You are asigning itemm to selected value in every step of the cycle, not adding, thats why only last one is selected

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check multiple items in ASP.NET CheckboxList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640640/check-multiple-items-in-asp-net-checkboxlist)

Comment: cbl_items is the ID of the checkboxlist guys

Comment: @Uriel_SVK thank you SIR! that helped a lot , just replaced the content inside the foreach to: Cbl_items.Items.FindByValue(itemm).Selected = true;